# I get tight muscles and very painful DOMs after I workout

Tags: workout, starting-strength, post-workout

I’m new to wheight lifting and I’m looking to build size but also lose some fat. Anyway, a day after my bicep workout I could barely extend my arm and it hurt like hell. Same thing for chest. If it’s about warming up the muscle, how would I go about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to working out, The firs time you put your muscles through hypertrophy, they are going to hurt badly and in fact get locked in place. If you keep it up when the pain starts to wear out you will slowly get used to it and your body won't be as stiff or painful.

Tearing the muscle fibres for the first time will be a shock to your body. Just stay consistent, get lots of rest and appropriate protein levels.

Stretching before and after can help reduce the pain, do this through performing the action in full range of motion but with a light weight but enough to ensure you feel your muscle stretching. On top of this look up stretches for the muscle group if you are really bothered by the pain.